# Commutative group stacks and Galois cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, derived-categories, algebraic-stacks

"Classically", if we consider an abelian variety $A$ over some number field $k$, we get a $Gal(\bar{k}/k)$-module $A(\bar{k})$, or equivalently a sheaf of abelian groups on the étale site $\text{Spec}(k)_{ét}$. In particular, we can apply the machinery of Galois cohomology.

My question is if there is a similar construction for abelian stacks. If we have commutative group stacks over number field $k$ with a short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$$
is there a universal way of extending the left exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow A(k)\rightarrow B(k)\rightarrow C(k)$$
i.e. something akin to $H^i(G_k,A)$? My thinking is that we have an exact triangle
$$A^\flat\rightarrow B^\flat\rightarrow C^\flat \rightarrow A^\flat[1]$$
in $D(\text{Spec}(k)$ on which we can apply the global sections functor. Would that give us something relevant?

Comment: This paper by Noohi might be relevant: _Group cohomology with coefficients in a crossed module_ Journal of the Institute of Mathematics of Jussieu, 10(2) (2011) 359–404. https://doi.org/10.1017/S1474748010000186 https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.0161

Comment: including the definition of $A^\flat$ looks like a good idea

Comment: @Niels, I appolozige, I assumed this is standard notation. Denote by $C(k)$ the $2$-category of complexes of abelian sheaves $G^\bullet$ over $\text{Spec}(k)$  such that $^G^i=0$ for $i\neq 0,-1$ and such that $G^{-1}$ is injective. Then there exists an equivalence of $2$-categories between commutative group schemes and $C(\text{Spec}(k))$, which we denote by $\flat$. My reference for this is Section 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.0285.pdf.